# How to ensure Python script runs by double clicking on Windows OS

Tags: python-3.x

I have two Windows 7 machines. On one machine I can run python scripts by double clicking on the `.py` file, however on the other machine the script does not execute, the command prompt will flash quickly and the script does not execute. I can execute scripts on both machines using the command line. I have the same version of python installed on both machines.

How do I ensure that a python script can be executed by double clicking the script on Windows 7?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python scripts stopped running on double-click in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521456/python-scripts-stopped-running-on-double-click-in-windows)

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and turning it back on?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Check if your .py files are associated with "python launcher" (Not just "python"). You can check that by right clicking the .py file and see:

[image: on Windows 10]

In my case, I have two machines of Windows 10. The one with Python 3.6 installed by choosing "Install Now" works perfectly. The another one which having the same version of python installed in a customized location has problems. It seems nothing to do with the environment path setting, as I could run python in the console mode correctly. So at the end, I was forced to uninstall the python, (then removing all the related paths manually if needed), and install it again with default setting "Install Now".