# Python script doesn't execute by doubleclick on Windows

Tags: python, windows, inheritance, scripting

For a project structure like this:

```
/tumblr
    /tumblr
        /module_foo
            __init__.py
            submodule_foo.py
        /module_bar
            __init__.py
            submodule_bar.py
        __init__.py
        bot.py
```

I was doing something like that:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\repos\\bot\\tumblr\\tumblr')

from tumblr.bot import Bot

class SubmoduleFoo(Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...
    # ...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    SubmoduleFoo()
```

The bot.py only defines a an empty class with some initializations:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\repos\\bot\\tumblr\\tumblr')

class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.settings = dict()
        # ...
```

If I call these scripts from command line they work:

```
python C:\path\to\submodule_foo.py
```

If I doubleclick my python `submodule_foo.py` "script" It doesn't work.

I think the problem Is caused by the inheritance, and calling the parent **init**

But since I'm just doubleclicking it, I don't know how to debug it properly.

I tried to include a:

```
with open('codes.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write("It Works \n")
```

Just after the `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement and doesn't work :$

My `PATH` variable (in windows 10) includes the `c:\python34` and `c:\python34\scripts`
I also have a `PYHOME` env variable that points to `c:\python34`

And I have already tried this solution: [Python scripts stopped running on double-click in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521456/python-scripts-stopped-running-on-double-click-in-windows) But it doesn't work for me.

I also tried to create these classes throught the python interpreter. And the import to tumblr.bot.Bot() was working

I'm running out of Ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your file output does not work then it is possible that python interpreter is not started at all. Right-click the file in Windows Explorer, find where it says "opens with", and press button "Change" it it looks incorrect.

Open DOS command prompt by typing `cmd` in Start, and try to run your script both with and without specifying the interpreter.

```
c:\home>python.exe myscript.py
```

or

```
c:\home>myscript.py
```

if #1 works and #2 does not it means Windows is not configured to open *.py files with the correct interpreter.

To see output when you start a script by double-click, you can show the error message like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
try:
# your code here   
# your code here   
# your code here   

except Exception as e:
    print("\nTHERE WAS AN ERROR PROCESSING YOUR REQUEST:", e, file=sys.stderr)
    input("Press Enter to exit...")
```

The `stderr` channel is highly recommended because by default Python prints to console in MS version of latin-1, and any Unicode characters will trigger an encoding exception. `stderr` does not have this limitation.

Comment: The interpreter that was set through the windows extensions was my python27 interpreter >_< The "Open With" method solved my problem. But I really appreciate your other insights ! I think that they will help me a lot in the future :)

Comment: Yep, had the same problem and this led me to the solution. Turns out, I had 2 different versions of Python installed. Running a script with the Python command in a terminal was running with 2.7, as expected. However, running via clicking on the script was running with 3.x and some of the functions I was using in my script did not work in 3.x. Thus, running with "python myscript.py" in a terminal worked fine but double clicking on the script did not. To get it working, I right-clicked on the script, went to Properties -> "Opens with" -> navigate to correct version of Python and select it.