# Running Python file by double-click

Tags: python, batch-file, python-idle

I have really annoying problem, I cannot run a Python file just by double-clicking.

I have tried to set it to open the file with `idle.bat` but that only starts IDLE editor on double-click, it does not run the Python file.

Comment: are you sure that `idle.bat` can run with arguments and it can open file in IDLE ? Did you try in console/cmd.exe `idle.bat script.py` to run `script.py` in IDLE ?

Comment: sounds like python isn't in your PATH

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python scripts stopped running on double-click in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521456/python-scripts-stopped-running-on-double-click-in-windows)

Comment: In Windows, you should right-click and select "Open with", then choose (or search) python.exe and check the "remember" box

Comment: Yes it can open files in IDLE it did. It opened python file in IDLE Editor on doubleclick.

Comment: @Don but what file i should choose? I choosed idle.bat and it doesnt run the python file it only opens it in IDLE Editor

Comment: BTW As soon as you get practice with virtualenvs, you wouldn't want to run a Python script with double-click

Comment: Current 3.x Windows installers install Python so that double clicking runs the file.  I am not sure if adding the python dir to path is required or not, but it may be.  With multiple pythons installed, `py -x.y program.py` in a console lets one select from multiple installed pythons.  If program.py is in a directory on sys.path, making it importable, `py -x.y -m program` works regardless of the current directory.  idle.bat is a different subject.  It is for running IDLE with preset arguments other than the defaults.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a Python script executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045113/making-a-python-script-executable)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What version of Python do you have installed?

You should write your own batch file to execute your python binary and your script.

For example, with a default Python 2.7 installation on Windows, this could be the entire contents of your script.

`myscript.bat`:

```
ECHO ON
REM A batch script to execute a Python script
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python27
python yourscript.py
PAUSE
```

Save this file as "myscript.bat" (make sure it's not "myscript.bat.txt"), then double click it.

Answer (score 11):

right click on the file->open with->choose default program->more options->select python.exe file and click on.

Answer (score 6):

Right click the file, select open with.  If you want to simply run the script, find python.exe and select it.  If you want to debug with IDLE, find that executable and select it.

Answer (score 2):

When I had both Py2 and Py3, and then removed the former, my script wouldn't run by double-clicking it either (but fine from console.) I realized my `__pycache__` folder (same directory as the script) was the issue. Problem solved when deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also start a Django app this way.  Once the Django server starts it enters a "wait" kind of mode so a batch file only requires two lines:

> ECHO ON
> python manage.py runserver

Manage.py can be in any directory, just keep the full folder path in the command within the batch file:

> ECHO ON
> python C:\temp\manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Ubuntu users.
Right-click on the file, then select open with, then choose your python version, it shode be in
`/bin` folder, usually it's `/bin/python3.exe`

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, using regedit:

- Under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, create key: `.py`
- Edit Default string value to be `py_auto_file` (or any other name you want to call it)
- Under HKCR, create another key: `py_auto_file` (or any matching name that you have just picked)
- Under this key, create nested sub-keys: `shell` --> `open` --> `command`.
- Edit Default string value to `"C:\path\to\your\python.exe" "%1"`

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 1: Create the Python Script (myscript.py) Open a text editor and write the Python script as follows:

import os
import random
import pandas as pd 

# Create the directory if it does not exist
if not os.path.exists(f'C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Desktop'):
    os.makedirs(f'C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Desktop')

# Generate new random data
names = ["John", "Jane", "Michael", "Emma", "William"]
ages = [random.randint(20, 50) for _ in range(len(names))]
states = [random.choice(["CA", "NY", "TX"]) for _ in range(len(names))]
salaries = [random.randint(25000, 80000) for _ in range(len(names))]

# Create the new Emp dictionary with random data
Emp = {"Name": names, "Age": ages, "State": states, "Salary": salaries}

DF = pd.DataFrame(Emp, index=[f"E{i}" for i in range(1, len(names)+1)])

# Save the data to a CSV file
DF.to_csv(f'C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Desktop\\file.csv', index=False)
Save this Python script as myscript.py.

Step 2: Create the Batch File (myscript.bat) Open a text editor and write the following lines:

@cd %DIR%

@python.exe myscript.py %* 

@pause

Save this text as myscript.bat in the same folder where you have the Python script (myscript.py).

Now, double click the bat file, it should work.

If you encounter issues running the Python script from the batch file, you may need to add the Python executable path to the "system's" PATH variable. Follow these steps to do so:

Step 3: Add Python to the PATH variable

Locate the path to your Python installation by using following code:

import sys
print(sys.exec_prefix)

For example, if you are using an Anaconda environment and your environment name is "myenv_name," the path could be something like C:\Users\%USERNAME%\miniconda3\envs\myenv_name.

Open the Start menu, type "Environment Variables," and click on "Edit the system environment variables."

In the "System Properties" window, click on the "Environment Variables" button.

Under the "System variables" section, find the "Path" variable, and click on "Edit."

In the "Edit environment variable" window, click on "New" and add the path to your Python executable (e.g., C:\Users\%USERNAME%\miniconda3\envs\myenv_name).

Click "OK" to close all the windows.

Step 4: Run the Batch File Navigate to the folder where you have created both files (myscript.py and myscript.bat). 
Double-click on the myscript.bat file to execute your Python script.

The myscript.py will generate new random data for the "Name", "Age", "State", and "Salary" fields each time you run the script. The new data will then be saved to the CSV file at C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Desktop\\file.csv.

By following these steps and adding Python to the PATH variable, you should be able to run your Python script successfully on Windows 11 using the batch file and generate different random data each time you execute the script.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution for non-Windows environments is to create a `.desktop` file for your script.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My script
Version=1.0
Exec=python3 /usr/local/share/myscript/myscript.py
Icon=/usr/local/share/myscript.png
Comment=Run my fabulous script, imagine annoji here
Type=Application
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Video;GTK;GNOME
```

If the script requires a virtual environment to be activated etc, you can do that in a one-liner (basically, run `/path/to/your/venv/bin/python /path/to/your/script.py`); for anything more complex, probably create a simple script which does all the necessary set-up, then run *that* from the `Exec=` line.

See also https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ and/or e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/342950/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-entry-to-launch-a-python-script