# Python idle to python.exe

Tags: python, python-idle

So I've made a script/code in python idle and want to run it on python.exe but whenever I do this the you can see the python window pop up briefly for a second before closing, and I want to run my code using python instead of idle, how can I do this?

Comment: What OS?  What does 'do this' consist of.  What does your program do?  It is possible that you have already done what you want to do -- successfully run with python.exe.  Why do you think you failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since I cant comment yet:

go to the command line and open the file location directory and type:   python filename.py

Comment: are you sure you do not have a syntax error in the code itself?

Comment: This is the default option for doing this. Are you opening the file in the correct directory ? E.g.: C:\Users\Docs\Folderl\>python nameoffile.py

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using two methods.
The first one is using cmd. 
Such as `YOUR_WORKING_DIR>python filename.py`
Another method is to create `.bat` (batch) file that executes your particular python code.
Let us assume you want to run `my_python_file.py` using a batch file. relevant script similar to this,

```
ECHO ON
python my_python_file.py
PAUSE
```

Save this file as `.bat` extension and just double click it!
Incase the above method didn't work for you, Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639740/running-python-file-by-double-click) answer.

Comment: I've tried both of these, the .bat file dosnt run and the filename.py comes up as syntax error

Comment: Have you set python in your  path variable

Comment: That's the problem when I try set python as a path variable or try open it already in the python command line it treats it as either not defined, not a command of a syntax error

Comment: Open cmd and type python and press enter. If it says "Python is not recognized as an internal or external command," then follow these steps.[follow this url](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/)

Comment: python: can't open file 'file name': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Ahh..try following. navigate to your working directory(the place where your python file located) using `cd` command. then type `python yourfilename.py` **NOTE**:  `youfilename` should be replaced with your actual filename.

Comment: The system cannot find the path Specified and if I put the whole path it says filename, directory name of volume label syntax is incorrect